# bitcoind: incorrect rpcuser or rpcpassword (authorization failed)

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, authentication

The host system is Linux Debian Stretch (9 / testing).

[The Bitcoin Core package for Linux](https://bitcoin.org/en/download) I have just downloaded and [verified](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/124323/82570) and [installed](https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#other-linux-distributions).

I have created the following file:

```
/home/myUsername/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
```

With contents:

```
listen=1
server=1
rpcuser=myUsername
rpcpassword=myPassword
rpcport=8332
rpcconnect=127.0.0.1
```

Then I have punched the following holes to my firewall:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8333 -m comment --comment "Bitcoin Listen" -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8332 -m comment --comment "Bitcoin RPC" -j ACCEPT
```

And forwarded the 8333 port from my router to the server.

I am unsure whether the second hole is necessary for RPC connections, but that's not the question now.

---

If I now run the following command as my regular user:

```
bitcoind -daemon -datadir=/raid1a/bitcoind/
```

It says:

> ```
> Bitcoin server starting
> ```

I wait for a few minutes for it to initialize and then invoke:

```
bitcoin-cli getinfo
```

With the result:

> ```
> error: incorrect rpcuser or rpcpassword (authorization failed)
> ```

I have a very long and complex password, could that be the pickle?

The debug log says only:

> ```
> ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:someport
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite I run both `bitcoind` and `bitcoin-cli` as the same user, it for some reason fails to find my personal config file located in standard location:

```
$HOME/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
```

So I have set up an alias:

```
bitcoind -daemon -datadir=/raid1a/bitcoind/ -conf=/home/user/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
```

Case solved.